# Handling asynchronous Firestore data reading in tableView - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to retrieve data from my simple Firestore database

I have this database:
[image]

then I have a model class where I have a method responsible for retrieving a data which looks like this:

```
func getDataFromDatabase() -> [String] {
    var notes: [String] = []
    collectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Notes")

    collectionRef.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }
        notes = documents.map { $0["text"]! } as! [String] // text is a field saved in document
            print("inside notes: \(notes)")
    }
    print("outside notes: \(notes)")
    return notes
}
```

and as a UI representation I have tableViewController. Let's take one of the methods, for example

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("tableview numberOfRowsInSection called")
    return model.getDataFromDatabase().count
}
```

Then numberOfRows is 0 and the output in the console is:
[image]

and I am ending up with no cells in tableView. I added a breakpoint and it doesn't jump inside the listener.

And even though I have 3 of them, they are kinda "late"? They are loaded afterwards. And then the tableView doesn't show anything but console says (later) that there are 3 cells.

If needed, there is also my method for showing the cells names:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("Cells")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel!.text = String(model.getDataFromDatabase()[indexPath.row].prefix(30))

    return cell
}
```

but this method is not even loaded (no print in the console) and this method is written below the method with numberOfRowsInSection.

I have also 2 errors (I don't know why each line is written twice) and these are: 
[image]

but I don't think it has something to do with the problem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Firestore is async, so notes is returning as an empty array before the data has been downloaded from the sever. Either populate a viewController variable and add a didSet observer or add completionHandler to your `getDataFromDatabase` method

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla could you, please, provide code solution? At least some smaller one as this is the first time I am implementing this. I understood your comment but I am not able to implement. Thank you.

Comment: @MapeSVK I just posted a solution. Hope it helps!

Comment: @MapeSVK didn’t really have a computer in hand. That’s why I didn’t post an answer. But you already have a good one with @Bhaumik’s answer

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Galo Torres Sevilla mentioned, `addSnapshotListener` method is async and you need to add completion handler to your `getDataFromDatabase()` function.

Make following changes in your code:

1. Declare Global variable for notes.

   ```
   var list_notes = [String]()
   ```
2. Add completion handler to `getDataFromDatabase()` method.

   ```
   func getDataFromDatabase(callback: @escaping([String]) -> Void) {
       var notes: [String] = []
       collectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Notes")

       collectionRef.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
           guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
               print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
               return
           }
           notes = documents.map { $0["text"]! } as! [String] // text is a field saved in document
           print("inside notes: \(notes)")

           callback(notes)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Lastly, call function on appropriate location where you want to fetch notes and assign retrieved notes to your global variable and reload `TableView` like below:

   ```
   self.getDataFromDatabase { (list_notes) in
       self.list_notes = list_notes
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
   }
   ```

Changes in TableView:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("tableview numberOfRowsInSection called")
    return self.list_notes.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("Cells")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel!.text = String(self.list_notes[indexPath.row].prefix(30))

    return cell
}
```

Comment: thank you mate, it works! Just one question. Why is this so complicated? Isn't this fundamental stuff? Probably I am doing it wrong way, right?

Comment: Glad that it helped! Only issue with your code is, you were not waiting for Firestore to download your data. So, `cellForRowAt:indexPath:` method was executing before download was complete. By adding completion handler, it solves that issue.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is refresh the table cell every time you retrieve the data. Put this code after you set your data inside the array.

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```